# css hover over transition

Tags: html, css

I have one question about my css hover effect.

This is my **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/sdADt)** page from `codepen`.

The problem is hover over image. If you click my demo page then you see what is wrong in my script.

When you hover over the image with your mouse first image is ok but when you move mouse another image my gradient color moving left.

Anyone knows solution ?

This is my CSS code for image hover transition and gradient color:

```
.abo_im {
  float:left;
  width:170px;
  height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ;
        -o-transition: all .3s ;
        transition: all .3s ;


}
.abo_im  img.height {
   width: 100%;
   height:auto;

}
.abo_im img {
  width:100%; 

}
.abo_im:hover {
  width:120%; 
  margin: 0 0 0 -10%; 
        -moz-transition: all .3s ;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ;
        -o-transition: all .3s ;
        transition: all .3s ;   
}
.gradient_c {
  position:absolute;
  width:170px;
  height:150px;
   z-index:1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));

    }
```

Comment: Just a tip: It's useless to define the `transition` properties both on normal and `:hover` selectors... Leave just the first one, and remove the properties from `:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element `div.gradient_c` is absolutely positioned and doesn't adhere to the `overflow: hidden;` add relative positioning to its parent and increase the width - **[updated demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGHJd)**

```
.abo_im {
    position: relative;
}
.gradient_c {
    width: 186px;
}
```

**Update** The problem is that you are adjusting an element with positioned decedents. They follow the increase width appearing as though they are moving

Changing `.abo_im:hover` to `.abo_im:hover img` will only affect the width of the image. [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fDIak)

Comment: thank you so much . Can i ask you another question about this problem ? 

in this css code have this line : `.abo_loggo` there is a background-image if you change it then add background-color:red and you see same problem is still one there. What can i do for this ? Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

change the width property it should work

```
.gradient_c {
  position:absolute;
  width:auto;//change this
  height:150px;
   z-index:1;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}
```